# Execute python from C#

Tags: c#, python, process

im trying to execute some python code from C#, so i have this code :

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"C:\Users\protieax\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe";
start.Arguments = "request.py 31.12.2016 01.01.2017 datatype";  // give filename, dates from the UI to python and query datatype
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

It should work but the C# doesnt find the python file.

What i should put in those 2 variables? Thanks

EDIT :

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"U:\Documents\entsoe-py-master\tests\test_data";
        start.Arguments = "request.py 31.12.2016 01.01.2017 datatype";  // give filename, dates from the UI to python and query datatype
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
        }
```

Here is my code modified with your answers. I have a new error :

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

At the line

```
using (Process process = Process.Stqrt(start))
```

Comment: You'll either need the python file in the current working directory, or in your path variable, or have a relative path for it from current working directory or just an absolute path.

Comment: where is you file ? right now it is searching for the file `C:\Users\protieax\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\request.py`

Comment: First, what does "C# doesnt find the python file" mean? Do you get an error? If so, post the error here.

Comment: @Franck That's almost definitely not the current working directory.  It's just the path to the python executable.

Answer (score 0):

You specified a U drive, presumably a network drive. I've never used a network drive in a context like this one but I tried it to find out if that's the problem. I mounted a network drive with U being the label. After running the code, it failed and gave me the same error. I advise making a copy of the desired python script into your current working directory instead, it would make things a lot more simple.